# Is it possible to deploy more than one rails app to one server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment

Is it possible to deploy more than one rails app to one server? and I mean more than one different Rails applications, not the same app.

Comment: Yes. See http://www.modrails.com/.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this, including the popular [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) system for Apache and nginx. Typically you can install as many applications as can be supported with the memory available, where you should budget about 100MB per active instance. More popular sites will require several active instances, where that means thousands of page loads per day.